# vim-syntastic and files without extentions

Tags: vim, buck, vim-syntastic

I have to use [buck](https://buckbuild.com/) for a project, and syntastic is returning lots of errors in buck's TARGETS files. Is there a way/documentation to declare that TARGETS file should not be checked ?

I could set the default behavior to passive, but I would like to avoid that if possible

Comment: Syntastic cares about `filetype`, not file extensions.  Set the `filetype` for your buck files to something consistent, then make that `filetype` passive in syntastic.

Comment: I see. I'll look into filetype then, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autoclosing my question as it was off-topic: the right way to do is to properly configure buck's TARGETS filetype (see [override python filetype detection in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779814/override-python-filetype-detection-in-vim/52779927#52779927)) and then to use syntastic configuration to set them to passive.