# override python filetype detection in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to detect buck's TARGETS file as 'buck' files instead of 'python', which is the filetype vim's currently detecting for them.

I tried to add `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile **/TARGETS set filetype=buck` to my .vimrc but it didn't seem to work.

What's the correct way to change a 'default' detected file type ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your autocmd is the way to go in principle; just omit the `**/` in the pattern:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile TARGETS set filetype=buck
```

see `:help autocmd-patterns`

Ideally, you'd have this line in a `.vim/ftdetect/buck.vim` file